# Pass props to styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am querying data for my react site using graphql from my CMS (prismic.io) in order to produce color themed pages. I want to pass a variable or props into my styled component to change the background color based on what is sent back from the CMS.

In the below example, my graphql query will return a HEX that has been inputted by the user, this would then be applied to buttons etc to theme that page.

The colour can and will change from page to page as the user will be selecting it within the CMS.

Any help would be appreciated. Code example below:

## Props

`props.data.case_study_color`

## Component

```
const ContactButton = styled.button `
  background: #004655;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

Comment: See the docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
const ContactButton = styled.button`
  background: #004655;
  color: ${props => props.color || '#fff'};
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

See [codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-leaf-hf2oq).

This would be the component code:

```
  .....component

  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("#fff");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL).then(data => {
      setColor(data.response);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ContactButton color={color}>White</ContactButton>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul - I have updated my question with a little more info but I probably should have been more specific. I am wondering how I can define `props.color` with the color that has been retrieved from the CMS?

Comment: Great - thanks Paul. I simplified it a bit so that I wasn't having to set the state and just pulled it the color directly from another component which I'll drop into another answer incase it helps anyone. Is there any issues with me not setting the state like `React.useState`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
const ContactButton = styled.button `
  background: ${props => props.caseStudyColor};
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 10px;
`;




<ContactButton caseStudyColor={'#004655'} />
```

Comment: thanks for the help @ramaoorthy_villi - the accepted answer was pretty much the same as yours so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As my solution was slightly different but based on Paul's answer it might be useful for someone else.

**Button Component**

```
const ContactButton = styled.button`
background: ${props => props.themeColor || '#004655'};`
```

**Color Component**

`const themeColor = props.data.case_study_color;`

**Button**

`<ContactButton themeColor={themeColor}>Get in touch</ContactButton>`